# Errors involving /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/ClassLoader.php

Tags: wordpress, extension, cache

Whenever I try to install/uninstall CiviCRM extensions or run Cleanup Cache, I consistently receive this error:

> Warning:
>   require(/home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/CachedExtLoader.8fc40bba39c0b8bd10ea54175cf9a6b3.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/ClassLoader.php on line 70
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   '/home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/CachedExtLoader.8fc40bba39c0b8bd10ea54175cf9a6b3.php'
>   (include_path='/home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/org.civicoop.pdfapi/:/home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/org.civicoop.civirules/:/home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.volunteer/:/home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.angularprofiles/:.:/home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm:/home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages:/home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/tecnickcom:/home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib:/home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear_exception:/home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/auth_sasl:/home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content
>   in
>   /home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/ClassLoader.php on line 70
>
> There has been a critical error on your website. Please check your
>   site admin email inbox for instructions.

civicrm.settings.php seems fine:

> global $civicrm_root;
>
> $civicrm_root =
>   '/home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/'; if
>   (!defined('CIVICRM_TEMPLATE_COMPILEDIR')) {   define(
>   'CIVICRM_TEMPLATE_COMPILEDIR',
>   '/home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/');

Wordpress 5.3.2
CiviCRM 5.22.0
PHP 7.3

The email sent by the system had almost the same message:

> Error Details
>   ============= An error of type E_COMPILE_ERROR was caused in line 70 of the file
>   /home/nkxwvwvr/public_html/staging02/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/ClassLoader.php.
>   Error message: require(): Failed opening required
>   '/home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/staging02/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/CachedExtLoader.697f143a9f2872e12a14e35583756c82.php'
>   (include_path='.:/home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/staging02/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm:/home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/staging02/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages:/home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/staging02/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/tecnickcom:/home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/staging02/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib:/home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/staging02/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear_exception:/home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/staging02/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/auth_sasl:/home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/staging02/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/log:/home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/staging02/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/console_getopt:/home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/staging02/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src:/ho

Comment: try reloading your php-fpm or ngnix or apache

Comment: The host restarted them. No difference. They say, "If the issue is still there, i would recommend having a developer look into this, as this appears to be PHP error." I even lowered PHP from 7.3 to 7.2. No difference.

Comment: "There has been a critical error on your website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions."  What does the mail say?  You could try manually removing /home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c

Comment: The email contained pretty much the same error as I see on the screen. I just placed the error in the original post.
Also, deleting templates_c doesn't help.

Comment: It's happening at one webhost and not another. The only difference in setup is that the failing webhost is using EasyApache.

Answer (score 1):

The hosting company sent me this instruction. It worked, and I'm back in business!

> "You need to add this in your .htaccess file to avoid problem, it is
>   caching related:"
>    `php_flag opcache.enable Off`

Answer (score 0):

I've been tearing my hair out on this one, attempting a clean CiviCRM install

Same error as above, during install. Clearly something to do with the database, as the install ran for a minute, and produced the error, but no tables were ever written to the database.

I know all requirements are met, as we already have two other running copies of CiviCRM on the same server.

My fix, for what it's worth, was to locate a copy of CiviCrm 5.28 (yeah, I had a very old backup lying around), install that, and then upgrade!
Still have no idea what the cause was, but at least now I have a clean install of Civi running.

Ubuntu Server 18.04
MYSQL 5.7.35
PHP 7.4
Attempted install - CiviCRM 5.41.2 on Wordpress 5.8.1

Might help someone (might not)