# Having issues updating to civiCRM 5.32.2

Tags: wordpress, upgrade

So I've downloaded the file to update to civiCRM 5.32.2 and I'm on WordPress 5.6.  When I upload the file to the plugins page it tells me that I need to overwrite the other version.  Cool no problem.  When I tell it to do that it tries for a few minutes and then it gives me a 503 error.

> Service Unavailable The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try
> again later.
>
> Additionally, a 503 Service Unavailable error was encountered while
> trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

If I then try to activate the new version of civiCRM the whole site crashes with a fatal error that says the following.

> Warning: include_once(/home/enaosj1vvfz0/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.users.php):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> /home/enaosj1vvfz0/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php
> on line 623
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening
> '/home/enaosj1vvfz0/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.users.php'
> for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php74/usr/share/pear') in
> /home/enaosj1vvfz0/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php
> on line 623
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'CiviCRM_For_WordPress_Users' not
> found in
> /home/enaosj1vvfz0/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php:624
> Stack trace: #0
> /home/enaosj1vvfz0/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(379):
> CiviCRM_For_WordPress->include_files() #1
> /home/enaosj1vvfz0/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287):
> CiviCRM_For_WordPress->setup_instance('') #2
> /home/enaosj1vvfz0/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(311):
> WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #3
> /home/enaosj1vvfz0/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(484):
> WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #4
> /home/enaosj1vvfz0/public_html/wp-settings.php(420):
> do_action('plugins_loaded') #5
> /home/enaosj1vvfz0/public_html/wp-config.php(89):
> require_once('/home/enaosj1vv...') #6
> /home/enaosj1vvfz0/public_html/wp-load.php(37):
> require_once('/home/enaosj1vv...') #7
> /home/enaosj1vvfz0/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(34):
> require_once('/home/enaosj1vv...') #8
> /home/enaosj1vvfz0/public_html/wp-admin/plugins.php(10):
> require_once('/home/enaosj1vv...') # in
> /home/enaosj1vvfz0/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php
> on line 624 There has been a critical error on this website. Please
> check your site admin email inbox for instructions.
>
> Learn more about debugging in WordPress.

I have all of my other plugins deactivated so I know it's not a conflict there.  I've tried using multiple themes so no conflict there.  I've even addressed caching issues as described in another thread ([Errors involving /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/ClassLoader.php](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/34790/errors-involving-wp-content-plugins-civicrm-civicrm-crm-extension-classloader-p))

The only other suggestion my hosting company had was to unzip the file myself and replace the files manually which just seems like a good way to screw up my data.

Comment: I don't think wordpress upgrades work via the plugin page. I think you do need to unzip the files yourself. See https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/wordpress/#now-upgrade-the-filesystem and the other upgrade instructions there.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the WordPress plugin update system. You must do it via either ftp or SSH. You will find the full documentation at https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/wordpress/

While complete and accurate, the comprehensiveness of that doc can be a little overwhelming. I created a checklist for myself to cover the bases on my server. It may be helpful to you. You can see my CiviCRM upgrade on WordPress summary here: https://kapn.net/support/civicrm-upgrade/

Some bits are very specific to me but they should be obvious. If it looks like gobbledygook to you then ignore it and focus on the official docs above.